# Rating correct record PHP SQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have no idea how to make "plus / minus" rating to the correct record, I tried to do this in while loop, which shows all the records, but it's rating only the first record. How to refer to correct record? I'm newbie in PHP. Here's my code:

```
if (isset($_GET['najstarsze']))
{   
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM wpisy ORDER BY id";       
}
else
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM wpisy ORDER BY id DESC";
}

$stmt = $db->query($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        echo "
        <div class='data'>
        ".$row['data']."
        </div><br>
        <div class='daneautora'>
        <b>Ocena: </b>".$row['ocena']."<br>
        <b>Nr: </b>".$row['id']."<br>
        <b>Nick: </b>".$row['nick']."<br>
        <b>E-mail: </b>".$row['email']."<br>
        <b>Wpis: </b><br></div>
        <div class='suchar'>
        <p>
        ".$row['tresc']."
        </p>
        </div>  
        <div class='ocena'>
        <p><a href='index.php?plus=true'>+</a> &nbsp; <a href='index.php?minus=true'>-</a></p>
        </div>
        <hr>                        
        ";
        if (isset($_GET['plus']))
        {
            $sql = "UPDATE wpisy SET ocena = ocena + 1 WHERE id = ".$row['id']."";  
            $stmt = $db->query($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        else
        {
            if (isset($_GET['minus']))
            {
                $sql = "UPDATE wpisy SET ocena = ocena - 1 WHERE id = ".$row['id']."";  
                $stmt = $db->query($sql);
                $stmt->execute();
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the link so it has a reference to the record you want to update. Try:

```
index.php?plus=true&id=' . $row['id']
```

You also probably want to update the `isset` to include this new parameter as well.

```
if (isset($_GET['plus'], $_GET['id']))
```

Then you need to use prepared statements with parameterized queries so you aren't susceptible to SQL injections. Here's an example:

```
$sql = "UPDATE wpisy SET ocena = ocena + 1 WHERE id = ?";  
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']));
```

Also when using `query()` you don't need `execute()`, that executes as well. The `execute` is to execute a prepared statement.

> PDOStatement::execute — Executes a prepared statement

-http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to move your block where you're setting rating (`if (isset($_GET['plus']))...`) outside `while` block
2. Use [parameter binding](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) instead of passing variable right in SQL query string to avoid SQL injection.

There is nice [PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)